# Vuex passing different arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Making a filter:

**Mutations**

```
export default {
 state: {
 filteredBrands: []
},

mutations: {
 showFilteredList(state, payload) {
   state.filteredBrands.push(payload);
  }
 }
};
```

**Methods**

```
    loadProducts(item) {
      axios.get('/api', {
      params: {
       per_page: 20,
       filter_machinery_brands: [ item ]
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      this.$store.commit(
        'showFilteredList',
        response.data
      );
    });

},
```

*`item` this is an input with a checkbox, when clicked, a request is made to the server for this category*

For some reason, the push does not work, why?
And I would like there to be a check, if the array is the same, then delete, otherwise add. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? You have any tool like vue devs tools to see what values have filtered brands? Or you only check if the list of elements is rendered? Vuex reactivity fails sometimes in arrays because doesnt "detect" the array changes with operations like push.

Comment: @MRMarkII as i can see an array comes in payload (using vue devs trools). But nothing happens, no errors.

Comment: Maybe as I said, vuex dont detect changes. Try it "dirty" by set in the mutation: let auxFilteredBrands = state.filteredBrands; state.filteredBrands = null; state.filteredBrands = auxFilteredBrands; Put it after state.filteredBrands.push(payload); It is dirty, but you can test it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can se an array comes in as payload. Then you are trying to push an array into an array. Which cant be done in either js or ts.

You can try set the value:

```
state.filteredBrands = payload;
```

otherwise you would have to do something like this:

```
state.filteredBrands.push(payload[0]);
```

If you wanna control for existing items in array, and assuming your are not always setting value, but pushing new values into your array. You can do something like this:

```
    if (state.filteredBrands.indexOf(payload[0]) === -1) {
        // Not in array
        state.filteredBrands.push(payload[0])
    } else {
        // is allready in array
        state.filteredBrands.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item === payload[0]) {
                state.filteredBrands.splice(index, 1)
            }
        })
    }
```

EDIT:
My assumption was right.

Your payload is an array
Your state is an array
-------> You are trying to push payload(array) into state(array) - which cant be done i js - This solution would after my suggestion be more clean:

```
payload.forEach((value, index) => { // Looping payload 
    if (state.filteredBrands.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        state.filteredBrands.push(value) // push if value not allready in array
    } else {
        state.filteredBrands.splice(index, 1) // if value is in array -> remove
    }
})
```

Comment: Something wont work, when i click again i got error with ```Duplicate keys detected: '9802555'. This may cause an update error.```  And if i use ```state.filteredBrands = payload;```, then this overwrites the previous array. ```state.filteredBrands.push(payload[0]);``` Only add one item from array :c

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can push an array into an array.
I guess the problem here is your vuex config.

Vuex state is a function, so it needs to be:

```
state () {
    return {
      filteredBrands: []
    }
  }
```

And if you are using Nuxt:

```
export const state = () => ({
  filteredBrands: []
})
```